# Effect of doubling channel lengths of MOS devices in common source amplifier

Tags: circuit-analysis

The example problem below asks to fill in a table with the effects on various circuit parameters as a result of doubling the channel lengths of both the NMOS and PMOS devices in a common-source amplifier (Case 2). I get the first row (case 1, changing bias voltages), but the second row confuses me. The red text is the given solution.

The question specifies "doubling the length of both transistors without changing anything else." This seems to suggest that the bias voltages at the gate should be constant, so the overdrive voltages shouldn't change, but in the third column the overdrive is halved. How is this possible? It also seems inconsistent with the rest of the answers since \$g_m=\frac{W}{L}\mu_nC_{ox}V_{OV}\$, so given these answers \$g_m\$ would be scaled down by 4, not 2, and then the rest of the answers don't follow from that.

Additionally, if the length is doubled and the overdrive is halved, then it seems the current should be reduced by a factor of 8, not 2 like the first column says. And given the process parameters in the problem statement, it seems lambda should also be halved, so \$R_o\$ should increase by a factor of 4, not 2.

[image: problem statement]